Compare two dicts containing lists and return removed items
I am comparing two dicts to get removed (not changed) items.
Minimal example:
prev = {'HOST_A': [['OS_TYPE', 'AIX'], ['HAS_COBOL', '0'], ['HAS_TUXEDO', '0'], ['IP', '10.111.160.68'], ['IP', '10.111.160.66'], ['IP', '10.95.0.112']]}

current = {'HOST_A': [['OS_TYPE', 'LINUX'], ['HAS_COBOL', '0'], ['HAS_TUXEDO', '1']]}


# return a dict that contains what is missing in current data
def get_deleted(a, b):
    answer = {}
    for ki, vi in a.items():
        try:
            vd = b[ki]
        except KeyError:
            continue
        ls_del = [i for i in vi if i not in vd]
        answer[ki] = {}
        answer[ki] = ls_del
    return answer



b = get_deleted(prev, current)
print('result dict:', b)

for k, v in b.items():
    if isinstance(v, list):
        isize = len(v)
        for value in v:
            # print(isize)
            if isize >= 1:
                print(k, value[0].rstrip(), value[1].rstrip())

Output:
result dict: {'HOST_A': [['OS_TYPE', 'AIX'], ['HAS_TUXEDO', '0'], ['IP', '10.111.160.68'], ['IP', '10.111.160.66'], ['IP', '10.95.0.112']]}
HOST_A OS_TYPE AIX
HOST_A HAS_TUXEDO 0
HOST_A IP 10.111.160.68
HOST_A IP 10.111.160.66
HOST_A IP 10.95.0.112

Expected output:
result dict: {'HOST_A': [['IP', '10.111.160.68'], ['IP', '10.111.160.66'], ['IP', '10.95.0.112']]}
HOST_A IP 10.111.160.68
HOST_A IP 10.111.160.66
HOST_A IP 10.95.0.112

How to modify the get_deleted function to get the expected output?
Code examples only with Python standard library, no external modules possible.

only IP's are removed, rest qualifies as changed

You are comparing the entire list, and ['HAS_TUXEDO', '0'] is not equal to ['HAS_TUXEDO', '1']. You need to compare the zeroth element of each.
def get_deleted(a, b):
    answer = {}
    for ki, vi in a.items():
        try:
            vd = [k[0] for k in b[ki]]
        except KeyError:
            continue
        ls_del = [i for i in vi if i[0] not in vd]
        answer[ki] = ls_del
    return answer

It would probably be an improvement to use more descriptive variable names (and ls_del seems redundant: just assign answer[ki] = [i for i ...]).
